# Navigating back from UIViewController causes crash

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I am just using this piece of code in `viewDidLoad` method. It only opens the web page in `UIWebView` and that's it. But when I go back to the previous view It cause crash.
here is the code:

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[moreWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: Can't figure out with this amount of code

Comment: give more details about that error.

Comment: I am not doing any thing extra except this code

Comment: When the app crashes it gives Bad Access warning

Comment: what code u r write in back button clicked method?

Comment: It's navigationItem left button by default to go to previous view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just stop loading like this:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
[moreWeb stopLoading];
moreWeb.delegate = nil;
}
```

it'll work fine.

Comment: If you ever re-use this `moreWeb` webView and its owning view controller, don't forget to set the delegate back on `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: 100% perfect answer by Simha.hb It worked perfect. thank you very much. Can you please explain the reason?

Comment: @Cyrille No problem, because here is poping to previous viewController. If again come to this controller all default properties will load again..:)

Comment: @IdreesAshraf yup, because you are poping while your webview loading is in process. So, we need to stop loading before leaving the current ViewController.

Comment: I was stopping it before as well. but it didn't work. when I set delegate to nil it works. what was the delegate method which was in running state other than load

Comment: When you stop the loading, the webview sends a message to its delegate. If its delegate is already released, it'll crash.

Comment: oh! Because of the delegate=self (currentViewController) which will be released after poping.